# Laravel Auth::Attempt authenticates only first time

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm getting a strange problem with Laravel.

After creating a user normally, user can login the **first time** but after this, `Auth::attempt` always fails. I can only login again by updating the user password via code and when I check database all passwords are hashed properly.

I can't seem to understand why this is happening. Here's my code

**Register method**

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Input::get('password');
$user->save();
$general = Role::find(3);
$user->roles()->attach($general->id);
```

**Login Method**

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$pwd = Input::get('password');
if (!($pwd && $username)) {
    return Redirect::intended('user/login')->withMessage('Emtpy username/password')->withInput();
}
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $pwd))){
    return Redirect::intended('user/dashboard');
}
elseif (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $username, 'password' => $pwd))) {
    return Redirect::intended('user/dashboard');
}
else {
    return Redirect::intended('user/login')->withMessage('Incorrect username/password')->withInput();
}
```

**User Model**

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($data) {
        $data->password = Hash::make($data->password);
        unset($data->password_confirmation);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: So apparently, the problem is from the boot method in user model, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Also, why does this affect the model, does it mean saving is always called even if the model is saving or not? Could this be a bug?

Comment: where are u making the call to the `boot` function in your model?

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help you with your login http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/

Comment: Sorry but I think you need it more than me

Comment: Why you need a boot method?

Comment: @rtuner - has my answer below helped? Do you need any more info?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I had tried using `setPasswordAttribute` first but had compatibility issues with frozennode administrator package. However, the bizarre nature of accepting login for first time (when no form of update is actually performed for user) still remains unexplained. I was able to solve my problem by overriding the default eloquent save method. I have also noticed that some others have experience [weird errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20812779/1261657) with the static::saving event.

Comment: "However, the bizarre nature of accepting login for first time (when no form of update is actually performed for user) still remains unexplained" - actually, it makes *perfect* sense. The login works the first time, because the original password works. But as you login for the first time, it *then* changes the password, so it wont work the second time. There is nothing weird or bug about it, it is because the wrong event handler is used.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are using the [wrong event listener](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).

You have incorrectly hooked into the `save` event, which is called *every time* there is a change to the user model (i.e. on both `creating` and `updating`).

This means *every time* the user logs in, and does some action (update login count, change their first name etc) - it causes the model to re-hash the already hashed password, thus rendering it broken.

There are two options to fix this.

Option one is to change the event to only work on the `creating` event. But this means later on when you need to update the user password, it will not be re-hashed correctly, so option 2 is better.

Option 2 is to not use any event, [and just use a mutator function](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) - which is designed for this *exact* situation.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

}
```

This way, no matter where/when someone changes the user password, it will be hashed, but only when a change is actually needed.

Comment: @rturner - has my answer helped? Do you need any more info?

Comment: yes thanks your answer is helpful. I had tried your second suggestions first and didn't want to try the first one because I was using frozennode administrator package. I think this is some sort of bug but nevertheless, this is a great answer... except I wasn't making any changes to user model.

Comment: But thats the thing rtuner, you might not have, but frozennode probably was, with a 'last login' or login counter etc - basically almost anything at all would trigger a re-hash with your original code.

Comment: There's nothing like that on frozennode. I had thought Zicaco entrust could be the culprit but I think I was able to reproduce it even after disabling it. If `boot::saving` doesn't malfunction, my solution wouldn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by overriding the default eloquent save method instead and manually making hash when creating user. Here is the code:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    if (isset($this->password_confirmation))
    {
        unset($this->password_confirmation);
    }
    if (isset($this->password))
    {
        if (Hash::needsRehash($this->password))
        {
            $this->password = Hash::make($this->password);
        }
    }
    parent::save();
}
```

However, I am still unable to find out why this bizarre experience was occurring, over and over again. I still have the code that reproduces the error (even with a clean install of Laravel 4.2 *as of July 22, 2014*) and can provide it to anyone who is interested in investigating this issue.

The packages I was using are Zicaco Entrust, and Laravel Frozennode.

Comment: I think the problem is that you weren't hashing the password when you register them. Auth requires you to use `$user->password = Hash::make($pass);` That's why when you edit the save method like this (which you should not have to do/ never do) it works because now it's being hashed.

Comment: No. @Samuraisoulification I specifically mentioned they can login the first time but unable to login the second time.

Comment: have you ensured that on register that the password is being hashed? Also when they login at first, does register log them on? OR do they register then log in? IF the get logged in at register, is it calling the login method, or something else?

Comment: Also, if you wouldnt mind humoring me, could you try changing the register method to use `$user-> password = Hash::Make(Input::get('password'));`

Comment: I checked the db. The first time, the user registers, the password is actually hashed. Somewhere, somehow, the password changes after login but there's no code that should fire `boot::saving` which is what I was discussing with @TheShiftExchange

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach is way to complex. Do it simple.

Change your register method to this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();
$general = Role::find(3);
$user->roles()->attach($general->id);
```

And throw away your "boot"-method.

Also (not really relevant, but I like doing it) you can change the login procedure to this:

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$pwd = Input::get('password');
if (!($pwd && $username)) {
    return Redirect::intended('user/login')->withMessage('Emtpy username/password')->withInput();
}
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $pwd)) 
    || Auth::attempt(array('email' => $username, 'password' => $pwd))){
        return Redirect::intended('user/dashboard');

    }
    else {
        return Redirect::intended('user/login')->withMessage('Incorrect username/password')->withInput();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me your problem is here:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $pwd))){
***return Redirect::intended('user/dashboard');***
}
elseif (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $username, 'password' => $pwd))) {
    return Redirect::intended('user/dashboard');
```

If your first Auth attempt fails using the username, it will return redirect out of the method before the second Auth attempt block. This may not be the overall issue you're facing, but it seems to be a erroneous piece of code nonetheless.

Comment: This code is correct. He is trying to log the user in via their username, and if that fails he then tries to log them in via their email. i.e. he is allowing both username or email login from the same form login